# I want to upload image from local system uisng apex:inputtext area rich text attribute as true

Tags: richtextarea

How can i upload Image in a rich text area in a VF page using apex:inputtextarea richText=true.

Current I am getting only webaddress option, but i want to upload file from loacl m/c as well

Answer (score 1):

I believe that security constraints prevent this behavior from happening. If you want to upload a file, you will need to use the  component:

http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm